# Azure DevOps - YAML Pipelines - Set number type template parameter value from Variable Group

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a Azure DevOps YAML template which accepts a Parameter of type is number. From the main YAML file, I need to invoke the Template file by passing a variable available in the VarGroup. Below is the code.

### main-pipeline.yml

```
variables:
- group: MyVarGroup
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
   targetType: 'inline'
   script: Write-Host "$(SomeNumber)"
- template: mytemplate.yml
  parameters:
  pSomeNumber: 123
```

template.yml

---

```
parameters:
- name: pSomeNumber
  type: number
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
   targetType: 'inline'
   script: Write-Host "PowerShell Task - ${{ parameters.pSomeNumber }}"
```

The above code works perfectly. However, in the main-pipeline.yml, if I replace 123 with $(SomeNumber), it throws an error as shown below

[image]

Comment: Hi @Prawin , could you kindly tell the latest information? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable $(SomeNumber) is recognized by system as String type. But here you defined the parameter pSomeNumber as Number type. Therefore, you meet the errror.

If there is no other concerns, I suggest to change the type as String.
Then it runs well on my side.

```
parameters:
- name: pSomeNumber
  type: string
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
   targetType: 'inline'
   script: Write-Host "PowerShell Task - ${{ parameters.pSomeNumber }}"
```

main yaml:

```
variables:
- group: MyVarGroup
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
   targetType: 'inline'
   script: Write-Host "$(SomeNumber)"
- template: mytemplate.yml
  parameters:
   pSomeNumber: $(SomeNumber)
```

I hope this could do some help. Thanks.